# Bypass Django form validator

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a really specific case that my Object can created in 2 ways, as legacy data (imported) or from zero.

My object has an Image field with some validators:

```
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='events', validators=[MinSizeValidator(350, 350)],
                            processors=[ResizeToFit(900, 350)],
                            format='JPEG', options={'quality': 99})
```

What I'm trying to do when the User Update the data, is bypass the Image Validator only if my object was imported, as bellow:

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(EventForm, self).clean()
        if 'image' in self.errors and self.cleaned_data['is_legacy']:
            del self._errors['image']
        return cleaned_data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of trying to make your form fit both cases, why not use 2 different forms instead? Should be simple to setup a form for each case.

Comment: My form is huge! I would like to have a DRY code

Comment: You can sublcass forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#subclassing-forms